# using hooks with react redux. Reducer not getting hit. No state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am working on a react application using redux with hooks. 
Here is my action creator below

```
    PostAction
    ***********
    import * as types from "./actionTypes";
    import axios from 'axios';

    const ROOT_URL = 'http://dotsuper.com/api'

    export function fetchPosts(){
        const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/post/getposts`)

        return {
            type: types.GETALL_POSTS,
            payload: request
        }
    }
```

Here is my reducer below

```
    PostReducer
    ************

    import _ from 'lodash';
    import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";

    export default function postReducer(state = [], action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case types.GETALL_POSTS:
          debugger;
          console.log(action.payload.data);
          return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, 'id');
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Here is what my store configuration looks like

```
    configureStore
    ***************
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
    import rootReducer from "./reducers";
    import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from "redux-immutable-state-invariant";
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

    export default function configureStore(initialState) {
      const composeEnhancers =
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose; //add support for redux dev tools.
      return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant()))
      );
    }
```

Here is what my component looks like.

My question is when I look at my devtools, the state for posts is
completely empty. When I set a debugger, my PostReducer is not getting hit. I think I am still
missing something. I don't think you can use connect with hooks. What do I need to do below
to have data in my state and be able to hit my post reducer?

```
    PostPage
    **************

    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import {fetchPosts} from "../../redux/actions/postActions"; 


    const PostsPage = () => {
        const [getPosts, setGetPosts] = useState([]);


        async function fecthData(){
            const res = fetchPosts()
        }

        useEffect( () => {
            fecthData();
        },[]);


        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Posts</h2>
                <p>
                This page is for all the posts.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default PostsPage;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check inside `fetchPosts` method, `axios.get` returns promise. you need to make 
   the method async and handle async data.
2. You need to dispatch the action in order to bind the action with the redux state.

```
    // PostAction

    import * as types from "./actionTypes";
    import axios from 'axios';

    const ROOT_URL = 'http://dotsuper.com/api'

    export function fetchPosts(){
        return async (dispatch) => {
          const request = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/post/getposts`); // returns promise.

          dispatch({
             type: types.GETALL_POSTS,
             payload: request
          }); 
        }
    }
```

```
    // PostPage

    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
    import {fetchPosts} from "../../redux/actions/postActions"; 


    const PostsPage = () => {
        const [getPosts, setGetPosts] = useState([]);

        const dispatch = useDispatch();

        useEffect( () => {
            dispatch(fetchPosts());
        },[]);


        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Posts</h2>
                <p>
                This page is for all the posts.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default PostsPage;
```

Comment: Wrong import bro, `useDispatch` must be imported from 'react-redux' not 'react'

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the action generator `fetchPosts()` inside your component, but you actually never dispatch any change into your state. If you look closely you'll see that you're `fetchPosts()` returns an object commonly known as actions:

```
{
   type: types.GETALL_POSTS,
   payload: request
}
```

So basically when you call the `fetchPosts`, you fetch something and you return this object. **No touching to the Redux state so far**

In the next step you should actually take this object and dispatch it to your store, like this:

```
    const action = await fetchPosts();
    dispatch(action);
```

Which when you use connect with `mapDispatchToProps` the connect will take care of it for you.

Check [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) to get a better grasp of the concept.

---

When using with hooks however, you can import these from `react-redux`:

`useDispatch` instead of `mapDispatchToProps` and,

`useSelector` instead of `mapStateToProps`

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import myAction from 'path/to/my/action';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const myState = useSelector(state => state.myState);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleClick = () => {
        dispatch(myAction());
    }

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: How do I do that? any code sample will be appreciated

Comment: This is actually happening when the component is loaded i.e on load which is why I am using useEffect. In your click event you called dispatch(myAction()) which is different from the dispatch constant you created. How will this work?

Comment: You have called myAction(), but you never dispatched anything into your Redux store so to expect any change. Redux stores don't care about your myAction() method, the only thing they care about, is `dispatch` which when called, it passes the value to the reducers and then, the new state will be created.

Comment: I was expecting you will use myDispatch(myAction()) instead of dispatch(myAction()). what is then the significance of const myDispatch = useDispatch() if you are not using it. ?

Comment: I am getting a red line underneath this "dispatch: Dispatch<Object>" Is there anything I need to import for this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Typescript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206612/discussion-between-evolon-and-user2320476).

Comment: No I am not using typescript. I am using jsx and my files have a .js extension

Comment: Check the imports and make sure you're import `useDispatch` from `react-redux` and not `react` package